# Use External IP in Google cloud with Kubernetes service to expose it to the internet

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, phpmyadmin, static-ip-address

I have a phpmyadmin service running on kubernetes cluster. I want to reserve an External IP (static) on google cloud to use with this service so that it could be reachable from the internet.
I have tried reserving an IP address on GCP and used it in the kubernetes service file as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: phpmyadmin
  name: phpmyadmin
spec:
  externalIPs: [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]  #the external IP from Google cloud
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: phpmyadmin
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

When I specify the `spec.type: LoadBalancer` then the service is accessible from the internet with the default IP address that is generated from the `type: LoadBalancer` .

I tried to change firewall rules for the External IP address by allowing Ingress on port 8080, but that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the `exteranlIPs`, you should set the `spec.loadBalancerIP` with the `spec.type` being of `LoadBalancer` value:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: phpmyadmin
  name: phpmyadmin
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: phpmyadmin
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "YOUR_IP_ADDRESS"
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

[Note that exposing your Pods through an external static IP only supports regional load balanced traffic hence your reserved static IP address needs to be regional.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#exposing_your_application)

For a global IP address, you need to expose a *HTTP(s) Load Balancer* through an `Ingress` object.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall rules are applied at the Instance level. they cannot prevent traffic from reaching the Load Balancer itself.

Reference : https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#firewall_rules

Your GKE LB service might be crating the **HTTP** Load balancer by default maybe you can checkout the **NLB Load balancer** : https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary-of-google-cloud-load-balancers

All port : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters#all_ports

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  labels:
    app: helloworld
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"8080":{}}}'
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8080-8080
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: helloworld
  # Use LoadBalancer type instead of ClusterIP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Example : https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/deployment/kubernetes/load-balancing/external-load-balancing